How to animate a coin toss with rigid body physics and maintain cloth collision?
I'm working on a Blender animation where I want a coin to fall onto a cloth plane. For the initial animation, I manually animated the coin falling into the cloth, and the collision with the cloth worked perfectly.
Now, I need to create a new animation where the coin is tossed first and then falls onto the cloth. I’ve animated the toss manually, but I need to make the coin a rigid body for the falling part to simulate the realistic drop onto the cloth. However, when I turn the coin into a rigid body, it cancels the cloth collision.
How can I transition from my manually animated toss to using rigid body physics, while keeping the collision with the cloth intact? Any advice on how to handle this switch would be really helpful!

Hello, if you bake the cloth animation, it won't change the way it is, or maybe I've misunderstood something?

Makes sense. I can either bake the coin toss from a rigid body sim or bake the cloth. I was looking whether there is a better way to do it all at once
